# Не могу отправить ответ пользователю в виде ссылок Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, coroutine

Возникла проблемка, с отправкой пользователю сообщения с несколькими ссылками
Я отдаю результат API

```
async def get_apart(state):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://barbara.roa.com/dom/states?api_key="+ API_KEY_RIA +"&lang_id=4")
    distr = response.text
    distr_list = json.loads(distr)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        latitude = "50.450001"
        longitude = "30.523333"
    location = geo.geocode(latitude + "," + longitude, addressdetails=True)
    info_loc = location.raw

    for list in distr_list:
        if list.get("name") in get_state(info_loc):

            state_id = str(list.get("stateID"))
            get_advertisement_id(state_id, data)
```

А вот тут хочу отдать пользователю результат, который отдает, но не так как нужно.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=UserDataCollection.price)
async def load_desc(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['price'] = message.text

    await edit_profile(state, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    await message.reply('Ваш запит в обробці')
    await message.reply(get_apart(state))
    number = get_apart(state)
    await message.reply(f'The current number is {number}')
    await state.finish()
```

Результат который отдает [image: результат который отдает вконце пользователю]

Comment: Что Вы хотите передать в `number`, какой результат? У Вас функция `get_apart(state)` не имеет `return`

Comment: У меня Get вызывает следующую функцию, там ретурн есть.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Переменную "number", изменил на "beautiful_url"
И добавил "await" перед get_apart(state)

```
beautiful_url = await get_apart(state)
```

Comment: Про добавление `await` тут ранее был ответ, правильный я так понимаю  Но как смена имени переменной помогла?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы) никак, по сути можно было бы оставить и намбер) добавив await :)